# Ordinary equation of the line $\{P + tA\}_{\ t\ in\ \mathbb R}$

Tags: geometry, parametric

Exercise 1 page 247 of "*Basic Mathematics*" by S.Lang.

**Question:** Is mine $\eqref{2}$ or the author's $\eqref{1}$ solution correct?

**Problem statement:** Find the ordinary equation of the line $\{P + tA\}_{\  t\  in\  \mathbb R}$ in the following case

$$P = (3, 1), A = (7, -2)$$

The author's solution is
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red] {3x + 4y = 13}  \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Which I belive is wrong, and could've possibly come from using points $P$ and $A$ as points of this same line, i.e. considering the line $\{P + t(A - P)\}_{\  t\  in\  \mathbb R}$, yielding the following equation:

$$(3, 1) + t(7 - 3, -2 - 1) = (3, 1) + t(4, -3)$$
Whose parametric representation is
\begin{cases}
x = 3 + 4t \\
y = 1 -3t
\end{cases}

Following the procedure suggested by the author, we can eliminate the parameter $t$ by multiplying expressions $x$ and $y$ by some amount, and adding them together:
\begin{cases}
3x = 9 + 12t \\
4y = 4 -12t
\end{cases}

It follows

\begin{align}
3x + 4y & = 9 + 12t + 4 -12t \\
& = 9 + 4 \\
& = 13
\end{align}

My interpretation of $\{P + tA\}_{\  t\  in\  \mathbb R}$ is all $t$ dillations of $A$ followed by a translation by $P$; the line parallel to $A$, passing through $P$.

With this interpretation I get
\begin{align}
P + tA & = (3, 1) + t(7, -2) \\
& = (3 + 7t, 1 -2t)
\end{align}

Which can be represented parametrically as
\begin{cases}
x = 3 + 7t \\
y = 1 -2t
\end{cases}

With the same procedure as before, we get
\begin{cases}
2x = 6 + 14t \\
7y = 7 -14t
\end{cases}

It follows
\begin{align}
2x + 7y & = 6 + 14t + 7 -14t \\
& = 6 +7 \\
& = 13
\end{align}

Yielding the ordinary equation
$$\bbox[yellow,5px] {2x + 7y = 13} \tag{2}\label{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Calculate a normal vector for the line $\vec n = \hat A=\binom{2}{7}$. Now pick a fixed point on the line $P = (3,1)$. Now a equation for the line is:
\begin{align*}
 \vec n \cdot \binom{x-3}{y-1} = 0 \Leftrightarrow 2(x-3)+7(y-1)=0 \Leftrightarrow 2x+7y = 13
\end{align*}

That is - you are right, and the book is wrong.